# Fourier transform in $S'$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

In my functional analysis class I saw the following problem:
define Fourier transform (of a function) as
$$\hat f(\xi)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{ix\xi}dx$$
then find the fourier transform of distribution (generalized function) $f(x)=\cos^2(8x)$ in $S'$
From all I know I started this way:
$$\langle \hat f, \varphi\rangle=\langle f, \hat \varphi\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\xi)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \varphi(x)e^{ix\xi}dxd\xi=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos^2(8\xi)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \varphi(x)e^{ix\xi}dxd\xi$$

So now I/m thinking of what should I do next: should I just calculate this integral? I tried, no success. And when I was looking for some examples of Fourier transform in $S'$ it always was about some "known stuff" - like $\delta$-function, Heaviside function, $\mathcal P\frac 1 x$, etc.
So may be I should use some fact like that?

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: I believe that for any distribution we need to use integral by parts in some place of the calculation.

Comment: Perhaps it helps you! 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle \mathcal{F} cos^2(8x) ,\phi \rangle&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}cos^2(8\xi)\mathcal{F}\phi(\xi)d\xi\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}cos^2(8\xi)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ix\xi}\phi(x)dxd\xi\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}cos^2(8\xi)e^{-ix\xi}d\xi\phi(x)dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathcal{F}cos^2(8x)\phi(x)dx
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So, we need to calculate the transform of the function $cos^2(8x)$.

Comment: @bigcoconut Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\cos^2(8x)$.  Then, we have for $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi\rangle&=\langle f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos^2(8x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k)e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\pi \phi(0)+\frac1{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(16x)\int_{-\infty}\phi(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\pi \phi(0)+\frac\pi{2}\left(\phi(16)+\phi(-16)\right)
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have in distribution

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(k)= \pi\delta(k)+\frac{\pi}2(\delta(k-16)+\delta(k+16))$$

Comment: is $e^{-ikx}$ right?

Comment: it is nice, but you loss me, are you using that $\cos^2 2x=\frac{1-\cos 4x}{2}$ and how you separate the integrals? Thank you

Comment: The distribution is an even function of $k$.  So it makes no difference whether you use $e^{ikx}$ for the FT and $e^{-ikx}$ for the inverse FT or $e^{-ikx}$ for the FT and $e^{ikx}$ for the inverse FT.

Comment: Distributions are linear functionals.  So, $$\begin{align}\langle f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos^2(8x) \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}(x)\,dx\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac12+\frac12\cos(16x)\right) \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}(x)\,dx\\\\&=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}(x)\,dx+\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac12\cos(16x) \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}(x)\,dx\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @weymarandres You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @bigcoconut Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @MarkViola, sorry, I had no time to think about this problem in previous couple of days. Now here are my doubts: I got it how you separated the first term, it follows from the fact that in $S'$ sense $\mathscr F\{1\}=\delta(x).$ And then I had a problem with the second term: I tried to swap integrals and decompose $\cos$ with complex exponents and find USUAL Fourier transform (see weymar andres comment), but it looks like there's no classic fourier transform for complex exponent as soon as integral does not converge

Comment: @BigCoconut Let $\psi(x)=e^{-ik_0x}$.  Then, we have for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi\},\phi\rangle&=\langle \psi, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ik_0x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) e^{i(k-k_0)x}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \phi(k+k_0)e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=2\pi \phi(k_0)
\end{align}$$

whence we deduce that in distribution 

$$\mathscr{F}\{\psi\}(k)=2\pi \delta(k-k_0)$$

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused how you compute this integral - two times by parts, using boundness of $\textrm{supp}\  \varphi?$ I tried with the interior integral, but didn't succeed

Comment: I am using the Fourier Inversion Theorem.  Note that $$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\,dk$$What happens upon setting $x$ to $0$?  Then, $$f(0)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\,dk$$Does that clarify things?

Comment: @MarkViola sorry now i am confused, please can you show a few steps more please? Thank you

Comment: @weymarandres What are you confused about?  Do you understand the Fourier Inverse Theorem?

Comment: @MarkViola, thank you. Well $\phi$ is any function, $\psi$ represent $\cos kx +i\sin kx$ right?  and $k_0=16 $ right? And why i need the particular case $x=0$, sorry you loss me again

Comment: what is happen in $\int\int \phi(k+k_0)e^{ikx}dkdx$ by the inverse transform as you wrote is $\phi(0)$? sorry again

Comment: @weymarandres What are you talking about?  The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k+k_0) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx=\phi(k_0)$$I never stated the result was $\phi(0)$.

Comment: Yes, you never state that, just i confuse with the other integral above with $f$, sorry @MarkViola